# Add string to same textBox instead of current string

Tags: c#, textbox

I have form which should change text inside textbox on button click. Text should be read from List, k.pojam. So on first click to the button text Box should show first element in list, second click second element etc. How to fix problem ?

```
//List<Karta> list; this list already has some number of Karta objects
int cardCounter=0;
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int currentCounter = 0;
   foreach (Karta k in list)
   { 
       if(cardCounter==currentCounter)
       {   
          txtBoxPojam.Text = k.Pojam;                 
          txtBoxPojam.Show();
          cardCounter++;
       }
       currentCounter++;           
  }
```

**edit** txtBoxPojam.Text += k.Pojam; // I need something like this, but instead of **adding** string I would like to write **another** string **instead** of current, because obviously txtBoxPojam.Text = k.Pojam; doesnt work?

Comment: Is it web application or Windows application? You need to check where other places cardNumber is used and if it being reset somewhere else before  next button click

Comment: windows form app. nowhere else, it should be very simple.

Comment: Did you check if list doesn't have all items with same value of Pojam property?

Comment: check my edit, I think I found problem. Because each element is different. and txtBoxPojam.Text += k.Pojam; will work. but not what I want, it will add next string to current

Comment: i need something similar

Comment: k.Pojam is a List<string>? `myTextBox.Text = "some string"; ` is correct...

Comment: List<Karta>, Karta has two fields string Pojam and string Opis, textBox.Text = k.Pojam;

Comment: It is very simple buddy. Why are so confused in making this work?

Comment: @J.SMTBCJ15 this is so true. It was last thing I was trying to do late last night, probably I was tired and made it so complicated :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int mainCounter = 0;
int totalItems = 0;
List<string> LstItems = new List<string>();

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   LstItems.Add("Test Item 1");
   LstItems.Add("Test Item 2");
   LstItems.Add("Test Item 3");
   LstItems.Add("Test Item 4");
   LstItems.Add("Test Item 5");
   totalItems = LstItems.Count();
}

private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
       if (mainCounter > totalItems)
       {
          //your implementation
          return;
       }
       txtNext.Text = LstItems[mainCounter].ToString();
       mainCounter++;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of txtBoxPojam.Text = k.Pojam; working combination is  txtBoxPojam.Text = string.Empty; and txtBoxPojam.Text += k.Pojam;

```
txtBoxPojam.Text = string.Empty;
int cardCounter=0;
private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int currentCounter = 0;
   foreach (Karta k in list)
   { 
       if(cardCounter==currentCounter)
       {   
          txtBoxPojam.Text += k.Pojam;                 
          txtBoxPojam.Show();
          cardCounter++;
       }
       currentCounter++;           
  }
```